# CakePHP - Find conditions not returning expected results

Tags: cakephp

I have an Invoice model, which has 2 fields determining its processing status.  One is technician_id, and one is date_processed.  They are both used for slightly different things, and each can be null.

I want to retrieve all those Invoices where date_processed is null and the technician_id is either null or is the same as the current user's id.

I thought I knew what I was doing, but obviously I have my Friday head on or something, as I can't get it to work.  Here's what I have at the moment:

```
        $conditions = array(
            'Invoice.date_processed' => null,
            'Invoice.technician_id' => array(null, $user_id)
            )
    );
```

I've also tried:

```
    $conditions = array(
            'Invoice.date_processed' => null,
            'OR' => array(
                'Invoice.technician_id' => null,
                'Invoice.technician_id' => $user_id
            )
    );
```

However, both of these return only those Invoices where the technician_id matches the user_id, and not those where the technician_id is null (the date_processed field is filtered correctly).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: first make your conditions and then assign it to find. bear in mind you will need to remove the conditions that are null

Comment: That's one hard to read indentation... Have you read [**the docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions) on how to define `OR` conditions?

Comment: Have made the find conditions easier to read, and separated them out in the code.  Yes, I've read the docs, and done similar things before - it just doesn't seem to give the expected results this time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution could be this:

```
$conditions = array(
  'OR' =>
        array(
               array('AND' => array(
                              array('Invoice.date_processed' => null),
                              array('Invoice.technician_id' => null)
                        )),
               array('AND' => array(
                              array('Invoice.date_processed' => null),
                              array('Invoice.technician_id' => $user_id)
                        ))
             )
);
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfectly.  Don't know why I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your first "or" statement wasn't working is because of how array's work in php, defining a key twice overwrites the first key.

So when you were doing this

```
$conditions = array(
        'Invoice.date_processed' => null,
        'OR' => array(
            'Invoice.technician_id' => null,
            'Invoice.technician_id' => $user_id
        )
);
```

It was more like saying this

```
$conditions = array(
        'Invoice.date_processed' => null,
        'OR' => array(
            'Invoice.technician_id' => $user_id
        )
);
```

The correct way of doing an 'OR' statement in cakephp without having the excessive 'AND' statement would be

```
$conditions = array(
        'Invoice.date_processed' => null,
        'OR' => array(
            'Invoice.technician_id' => array(null, $user_id)
        )
);
```

Comment: Thank you - I see what you mean.  Helpful to know.